# Multiple google search results only not working

Tags: javascript

how to add multiple google search results only on one page:
my code is this code not working.. I want to view results only without search boxes depending on specific tags :

I'm trying on multiple codessome of them return one search result and ignore the second and some of them not return any thing

```
  function gcseCallback() {
                            if (document.readyState != 'complete')
                                return google.setOnLoadCallback(gcseCallback, true);
                            google.search.cse.element.render({ gname: 'gsearch', div: 'results', tag: 'searchresults-only', attributes: { linkTarget: '' } });
                            var element = google.search.cse.element.getElement('gsearch');
                         element.execute('Specific tag');
                        };
                        window.__gcse = {
                            parsetags: 'explicit',
                            callback: gcseCallback
                        };
                        (function () {
                            var cx = '00999830932:uhtgng';
                            var gcse = document.createElement('script');
                            gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                            gcse.async = true;
                            gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                              '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
                            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                            s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
                        })();
                    </script>

                    <div id="results"></div>

  function gcseCallback() {
                            if (document.readyState != 'complete')
                                return google.setOnLoadCallback(gcseCallback, true);
                            google.search.cse.element.render({ gname: 'gsearch', div: 'results22', tag: 'searchresults-only', attributes: { linkTarget: '' } });
                            var element = google.search.cse.element.getElement('gsearch');
                         element.execute('Other Tag');
                        };
                        window.__gcse = {
                            parsetags: 'explicit',
                            callback: gcseCallback
                        };
                        (function () {
                            var cx = '0099983093302884:uhti3ng';
                            var gcse = document.createElement('script');
                            gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                            gcse.async = true;
                            gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                              '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
                            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                            s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
                        })();
                    </script>

                    <div id="results22"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution Put every search section in an separated  then call the two iframes in your page